How do I remove the top left icon in the title bar of Visual Studio Code?
How do I remove the top left icon in the title bar of Visual Studio Code?

I tried modifying it from settings.json but I didn't know which property is right!
Also tried looking for an extension but didn't find any.
It is so important to me because we not allowed to work in Visual Studio Code in our company, and I have to make it look like the one they chose.

You're using Windows, yeah? That icon doesn't exist in Ubuntu (Gnome 3.36)

There is no built in setting that controls this. The quickest way I can think of is to open the developer tools of Visual Studio Code and disable it.
Press Ctrl + Shift + P to open the command palette, then select "Developer: Toggle Developer Tools".  This will open a developer tools window similar to Google Chromes. Find the <a class="window-appicon" style="app-region: drag;"></a> element in the HTML, click on it, and then disable the background-image CSS property:

The downside is you'll probably need to do this every time you open Visual Studio Code.
Alternatively, you can try and modify the CSS file that holds this information.  For me, it was located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench in the workbench.desktop.main.css file.  However trying that didn't seem to do anything (perhaps VS Code does some sort of caching).  The class is:
.monaco-workbench .part.titlebar>.titlebar-container>.titlebar-left>.window-appicon:not(.codicon)


You should probably adhere to your company's policies though.

Thanks for your reply i go with the first suggestion beacause i didnt found the (\Microsoft VS Code) folder in my  program file maybe i need to connect as admin witch i can't.
Thank you

You can use the custom CSS and JS loader to set default css styles for vs code whenever it is opened.
Just add the styles


It's best to take a look at Glenn Raya's video, he showed and explained how to customize vs code with custom CSS styles and JS scripts.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_I0bySQoCs
